# Do all topological manifolds admit locally flat embeddings into R^n?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology, manifolds, topological-manifolds

In his 1969 paper “Locally flat imbeddings of 
topological manifolds” Lees proved that a closed oriented
second countable topological manifold admits a locally flat embedding into some R^n.

Does the same result hold if the manifold is not required to be closed or oriented?  If so, is there a published reference?

Comment: Remark 5.21.(2) in http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0166864100000134 states "Results of Dancis  show that a proper continuous map of a q-manifold to an n-manifold can be approximated, taking boundaries into account, by locally flat embeddings if $q$ is much less than $n$". The paper linked above is  "Topologically, quasiconformally or Lipschitz locally flat approximation of embeddings" by Jouni Luukkainen. Thus start from a proper function on your manifold (eg, distance to a point), multiply the codomain by some $R^N$ and approximate.

Comment: @IgorBelegradek: Indeed, the cited paper by Dancis does not make any assumptions about the manifold.
What does “distance to a point” mean in the context of arbitrary topological manifolds?

Comment: Disclaimer: I did not read Dancis paper carefully which is why I am not posting this as an answer. Regarding "distance to a point": any topological manifold is a finite dimensional locally compact metric ANR, and hence it embeds into some $\mathbb R^n$ as a closed subset (google the above phrase to locate a reference). The distance to a point in $\mathbb R^n$ defines a proper continuous function on any closed subset.

Comment: @IgorBelegradek: Many thanks for the clarification.  Isn't such a closed embedding into R^n itself a proper map?  (Proper means preimages of compact subsets are compact, in R^n compact subsets are precisely bounded closed subsets, and intersecting a bounded closed subset witha closed subset again gives a closed subset.)  This seems to make the other two steps (distance function and multiplication by some R^N) redundant.

Comment: Yes, this works too.